# Do long-cooked pasta and brown rice lose more minerals than short-cooked types?

Tags: pasta, rice

There are many different types of brown rice and whole grain paste that one can buy. Some need to be cooked for 25 minutes while others only need to be cooked for 8 minutes. I was wondering if rice or pasta that needs to be cooked for longer will lose more of the minerals as these may leach into the water.

Comment: You may want to update and clarify your question (especially the title); typically nutrition-related requests are off-topic for this site.  We're a bunch of enthusiastic amateur cooks, not nutritionists.  If what you're really asking is *Will my pasta lose its vitamin/mineral content the longer it boils?* then we can probably be more helpful.

Comment: Logophobe is right; we don't answer questions on nutrition. We could indeed answer something highly technical, such as whether more vitamins will leach out, but we can't tell you if this has any effects on your health. Maybe leaching is irrelevant because you use up the water too? Maybe all the vitamins get destroyed by heat anyway, leached or not? We can't answer these questions, so please don't take any answers to mean that some way of cooking is more or less healthy.

Comment: There was a question years ago on here about cooked vs. raw food ... and it's difficult to discuss nutritionally, as cooking may destroy some compounds while converting other nutrients to make them bio-available.  Your question is equally deceptive, as 'short cooking' rices are typically par-cooked, so they've already had this process done to them, just not enough to fully cook them.

Comment: I changed vitamins to minerals, unlike vitamins, the minerals stay in the pasta or rice unless they are leached out. Also, whole grain products are an important source of minerals such as magnesium while you'll typically get the B-vitamins from many other sources as well.

Answer (score 1):

I love the subject of nutrition. According to the charts I looked at in the past (I had the same question), only potassium seems affected by cooking and only a slight lose is shown in the charts.

Comment: We're really a food and cooking site, not a nutrition site, so unfortunately this may not be the best place to to express your love of nutrition. We do take very specific questions about what happens to nutritional contents during cooking, but not from a standpoint of what's healthy and what isn't, just things like this question - what happens to the minerals during cooking. On that note, the discussion of what "must" be done to brown rice for nutritional reasons is definitely off-topic, so sorry, but I'm going to edit it out.

Comment: As for the answer: where did you find these charts? We really like when people cite their sources and make it easier to find out more.